# what does the the "set-forming operator" $\{ \cdots \}$ actually do?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

the statement
$$
S = \{1,3,4\}
$$
looks a little like a function. informally the arguments are the three numerals, the function is represented by the brackets $\{$ and $\}$ and the image is the "newly-formed" set $S$. it is true the function notation is typographically nonstandard. but no more so than $e^x$ or $\lceil \pi \rceil$. i think i have seen the phrase "the *set-forming* operator". is such talk merely the result of succumbing to an irresistible temptation to *abuse notation*?

**question** what is the underlying semantics of this convenient shorthand? what steps have been taken to formalize its application?

Answer (score 2):

In the usual development of set theory, based on ZFC, one introduces defined function symbols, overloading the braces-notation to write a unary operation as $\{x\}$, a binary one as $\{x,y\}$, a ternary one as $\{x,y,z\}$, etc.  If one didn't want to overload a symbol, one could write $C_1(x)$, $C_2(x,y)$, $C_3(x,y,z)$, etc.  (And then I'd write $C_0$ for the empty set.)

Comment: thank you Andreas. that helps. an auxiliary question raised by your answer is that presumably the co-domain for each $C_i$ should be specified (probably usually implicitly) by context, otherwise it would have to include all specifiable sets. the $\{ \cdots \}$ notation seems to make use of a little ambiguity in this regard, as well as in its argument list. forgive me if this seems naive. i have little understanding as yet of "universes", or the relation between metamathematics and formal systems

Comment: Note that my answer was about defined function *symbols* adjoined to ZFC. In a model of ZFC, these would have as their codomain the underlying set of the model. In "ordinary usage" they won't have a set as codomain (but the entire universe of sets, if your ordinary usage lets you talk about such classes).